# Splunk query reference field in joined data

Tags: splunk, splunk-query, splunk-formula

*Full disclosure, I am very new Splunk so I may explain my question incorrectly.*

I have two data sources and was given a query to pull data from them individually. I am trying to join this data together so I can create some type of chart, but I am unsure of this would be a join/search etc.

My initial query is as follows:

This allows me to search through the mail logs by sender address and show all emails with a `bcSendAction=1`, which is a successful send.

`index=mail sourcetype=barracuda [search index=mail sourcetype=barracuda bcSender="someemail@domain.com" | table  bcMsgId] bcSendAction=1`

The result of this search is as follows:

[image]

Now, my other search is a log that shows all of the sender email addresses during a certain time period. I would like to use the result of this (the email value) in the first search so that I don't have to hard-code the `bcSender`, but rather have it use the results from the other source.

```
// Returns an email address
index=mail sourcetype=sendmail_syslog *@sfdc.net |  
rex field=from "<(?<from>.*)>" | 
table from | dedup from
```

I was able to parse the log and pull out just the email addresses that I want to use to plug into my first search.

I followed a few emails and tutorials, but a lot of the joins I was seeing only used two different sources/datasets and didn't use the `search` as I did in my first query.

My attempt at this was something like:

```
index=mail sourcetype=sendmail_syslog *@sfdc.net 
|  rex field=from "<(?<from>.*)>" 
| table from | dedup from 
|  join from 
    [search index=mail sourcetype=barracuda [search index=mail sourcetype=barracuda bcSender=from | table  bcMsgId] bcSendAction=1]
```

I don't know that I am referencing the email from the first result set correctly.
Can someone point me in the right direction with how to approach this search?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your request properly, then you need 3 steps:

1. get the sender addresses from `index=mail sourcetype=sendmail_syslog`
2. use these sender addresses to get a list of messageID's from `index=mail sourcetype=barracuda`
3. use these messageID's to finally get the events you are looking for

This sounds like you need a subsearch (for getting the sender addresses) inside of another subsearch (for getting the messageID's), meaning your own attempt was pointing in the right direction already.

Try something along these lines:

```
index=mail sourcetype=barracuda bcSendAction=1
  [ search
    index=mail sourcetype=barracuda
      [ search
        index=mail sourcetype=sendmail_syslog *@sfdc.net 
        | rex field=from "<(?<bcSender>.*)>" 
        | stats count by bcSender
        | fields bcSender
        | format
      ]
    | stats count by bcMsgId
    | fields bcMsgId
    | format
  ]
```

I can not really verify it without having your data, but I'll try to explain what it's supposed to do. Let's start from the innermost subsearch.

- Line 4 starts the innermost subsearch
- Line 5 selects the events in from which you generate the address list
- Line 6 extracts the addresses directly into the field `bcSender`. (We could extract it to the field `from` first and then rename it, but this is more direct.)
  We need the fieldname to be `bcSender` for the outer search.
- Line 7 is a different way to deduplicate by bcSender and at the same time reduce the amount of data which needs to be sent back from indexers to the searchhead (if you have a distributed environment).
- Line 8 gets rid of all the fields we don't require. They would be problematic with the following format command.
- Line 9 passes the results back to he enclosing search in a way so it can be used as part of the search string.
- Line 10, of course, closes the innermost subsearch.

Now let's have a look at the outer subsearch.

- Line 2 starts the subsearch.
- Line 3 selects the events from which we can get the messageID's. This is, of cause, augmented by the enclosed subsearch we've just discussed.
- Line 11 again is a way to dedup the messageID's.
- Line 12 again limits things to the field we need.
- Line 13 passes the found messageID's to the outermost (main) search in a such a way that they become part of the search string.
- Line 14, you already know, closes the subsearch.

And the outermost search:

- Line 1 selects the data you are targetting and is augmented by what the subsearches pass to it.

Comment: That is awesome, thanks so much for the detailed reply. I am going to test here shortly and let you know. Out of curiosity since I'm not terribly familiar with Splunk, does the date search apply to all of the searches, or only the outer/inner? For example, if I chose "Today", will it apply that date to the results of all 3 searches, or do I need to be excplicit?

Comment: @SBB: The selected timerange is valid for all three searches. If you want to change the timerange of one of the searches you'll need to use earliest= latest= for that (sub-)search.

Answer (score 0):

That one side of the `join` is a single field indicates it is a good candidate for a subsearch.  Subsearches run first and their results then become part of the main search.

```
index=mail sourcetype=barracuda bcSendAction=1 
[ search index=mail sourcetype=sendmail_syslog *@sfdc.net 
  | rex field=from "<(?<from>.*)>" 
  | fields from | rename from as bcSender | format ]
```

It's important that the result of the subsearch contain a field present in the main search.  That's why I used `rename`.

After the subsearch runs, you get a search that's equivalent to this:

```
index=mail sourcetype=barracuda bcSendAction=1 (bcSender="someemail@domain.com" OR bcSender="anotheremail@domain.com")
```

Comment: This looked promising, but I have having an issue with no events being returned. In my initial example, 2 events are returned. One event doesn't contain the `bcSender` or `bcSendAction`, the other does. The `bcMsgId` is what those two events have in common and allow me to group together so that I can find the event using the `bcSender` and `bcSendAction` values. I believe I still need that to exist in order to make this work.